# Is Yoga a good synergy for my routine to improve flexibility?

Tags: flexibility

All,

I started working out 5 / 6 days a week since December previous. My routine involves alternating days of bodyweight training and running. All in all I am happy with my routine and see noticeable consistent results. Unfortunately as my strength improves, I am beginning to hit the limits of my body's flexibility when attempting more complex movements.

These issues stem from being grossly overweight for many years (23 stone @ 6ft) but I know they can be fixed since I my bodyweight and running training routine has done wonders for my general health and fitness.

I have been researching yoga as a way to improve my flexibility, would yoga be a good match? Is there a specific type of yoga I should look to, or are there other forms of flex training people have experience with?

I have included my current routine below. I would like to incorporate flex training into all 6 days if possible. Cheers

**Bodyweight Routine (3 Days)**

- 5 x Atomic Pushups (TRX)
- 5 x Lunges (Free Standing)
- 5 x Spiderman Pushups (Free Standing)
- 5 x Unweighted Squats (Free Standing)
- 5 x Pullups (TRX)

*Repeated as a set until the first non conforming rep of any exercise*

**Running Routine (3 Days)**

- Day 1 : 5K under 35 mins
- Day 2 : 5K any pace
- Day 3 : 5k under 35 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoga can - among other things - improve your flexibility, for example, see this article in [YogaJournal](http://www.yogajournal.com/practice/209). The article argues that yoga both addresses the physical side of flexibility (muscle, ligaments, joints etc) and the neuro system part of flexibility.

My own experience of yoga is that is has helped me to be more flexible(for example, no problems with third world [squat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADWqYRMcAp0) now, big problems before), better balance (for example, no knee problems any longer when down hill skiing) and more aware of posture (less problems with my back).

To get started, find a yoga "dojo" that fits your style/perspective and take some classes regularly for a few months. For me, I liked the ones that focus on the physical side better than the ones focusing on the spiritual side.

Yoga is then quite easy to integrate in daily training routines and also a way of "going to gym" training that is easy to bring your spouse too.

For example, you could do a short yoga routine as a warm-up for both your Body weight routing and your Running routine.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to develop flexibility while continuing to burn body fat, I can highly recommend Hot (Bikram) yoga.

I have tried gymnastics for adults and capoeira to develop flexibility, but the fastest results I have achieved were while doing Bikram yoga. (I've heard that due to the heat you can push your body to the limits, but it can be [dangerous](http://breakingmuscle.com/yoga/hot-yoga-the-dangers-and-myths-you-need-to-know)).

I have also burnt a lot of fat while doing Bikram because you sweat continuously.

Comment: You don't burn fat from sweating. Unless you are sweating because you are working hard. Sweating due to being in a heated room (such as a sauna) does not burn any extra calories, meaning you will not burn fat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes yoga is a good synergy for your routine to improve flexibility of your body.Synergy health is a exercise program run by an organization to improve your lifestyle.Yoga classes can be better option for everyone or all body for their fitness levels.Yoga can improve your health and strength of your body.To maintain the weight,health,stay fit,be active,for better immunity of the body you have to do the regular yoga and meditation.